# how to share activity (edit task/event) for other users

Tags: security

I have contacts set to private and use sharing rules to open up access to other sales users.  I have a scenario where an account executive would like to have other sales support users below them in the role hierarchy edit tasks that are assigned to the account executive.  I still have not been able to enable edit ability to the support users.  It keeps coming up Insufficient Privileges when the user tried to edit the activity.  Is there a way to share the activity with other users so they can edit the activity owned by an Account Executive at a higher level in the role hierarchy?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3):

Some options:

- change the activity ownership to the sales support. It will still be viewable by the Account Executive in the activity list view using the 'My delegated activities' option
- enable 'Shared Activities' so the Account Executive can add other
  users to the Activity 'team'. Also see
  https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=activities_shared_definitions.htm&language=en_US

Comment: 'Shared Activities' is enabled, but how do you add users to the Activity "team"?  So, a sales support user created the activity and assigned the event to the Account executive.  Now, another sales support team member needs to go to that activity and edit it.  Getting Insufficient Privleges.  How can I add different users to this activity team so they can all edit it?

Comment: OK now I understand better. Indeed you cannot add extra users to the task. Only the assigned user or people above him/her in the role hierarchy can edit the task, unless they have 'Modify all' permissions (http://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=activities_access.htm&language=en_US). There's an idea for assigning tasks to queues here, which is always a bad sign ;-) https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=087300000007HC0AAM  Some people have even created a custom task object to work around shortcomings like this one..

Answer (score 0):

You can use calendar sharing to specific group of users. 
https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/204/latest/en-us/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_groupcal_cheatsheet.pdf

Comment: You should include the relevant content from the link if it answers the question.