# OWD vs Role hierarchy on Activities

Tags: permissions, security, permission-sets, role-hierarchy, owd

I have a problem with setting up data security as per client's needs. What I want is for **any user to have access to any Task regardless they are the owner or not of the task or the account or contact (in this case) to which the Task is associated**.

I've tried setting everything up in so many ways, nothing worked. Must mention there is a hierarchy in place also,

example: user A (manager) and user B (subordinate) in the hierarchy. OWD = Controlled by Parent, Permission Set = View All, Read, Edit for both Account and Contact.

I am out of ideas on how to achieve this so if anyone has found themselves in the same situation or has an idea on it?

Thank you!!

Comment: Is this answer your question https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/30899/how-to-share-activity-edit-task-event-for-other-users?